# Verification of User Entered Google map URL

Tags: php, google-maps

Hi I am currently working on a real estate site. the users on the website can post ads related to their property. they also have an option to enter google map url if they want their ad to have a map of the location. 
My problem is how will i verify if a url entered will open a map or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old, long URLs look like these:

```
http://maps.google.com/?ll=<longitude>,<latitude>&t=<map type>&z=<zoom level>
```

- Longitude and latitude are floats so basically numbers plus dot plus numbers.
- Map type is `h` for satellite and `m` for map
- Zoom level is a number between 1 and 19

Have in mind that there are also some other, additional parameters possible.

The [new, shortened URLs](http://googlesystem.blogspot.de/2010/07/shorter-google-maps-urls.html) look like these:

```
http://g.co/maps/<string>
```